# git using OSX keychain, even though credential.helper NOT configured?

Tags: git, macos, github, https

Why, on my OSX 10.8.5 system, does `git` (version 1.8.5.2/Apple Git-48) allow me to access `https://github.com/...` URLs without challenging me for username/password, even though a `credential.helper` is **not** in my `git` configuration?

While it's true that my github.com username/password are in my OSX keychain, running
`git config -l` shows only the following:

```
difftool.kdiff3.path=/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
difftool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
difftool.prompt=false
diff.tool=kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.path=/Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
mergetool.kdiff3.trustexitcode=false
mergetool.keepbackup=false
merge.tool=kdiff3
```

i.e., no `credential.helper` configured.

Yet I was able to clone a private repo (not owned by me, though my GitHub account has been made a member of the organization that owns it) using its https address, unaltered from how it appears on its GitHub page:

```
% git clone https://github.com/organization/project.git
```

i.e., no username or password interpolated into the URL.

I reviewed the other answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343068/1337498) as well, but none of them seem to apply to my situation, e.g., I don't have a `.netrc` file, I'm not using `ssh`, I`m not using GitHub auth tokens, etc.

I've seen other people waste lots of hours trying to figure out why `git` is either doing something they don't want, or *not* doing something that they *do* want. It usually comes down to `git` having too many obscure and partially-overlapping options that are impossible for most mortals to keep straight in their heads, or remember that they've enabled at some time in the past.

I suspect that I've either fallen into that kind of trap, or that there is some kind of OSX-specific magick going on under the covers that I'm not aware of -- like, I dunno, maybe Apple decided to be "helpful" and build keychain access into "Apple Git-48" without requiring the user to set up a credential helper.

(BTW, I considered asking this in the AskDifferent SE, but decided to ask it here instead, since I figured there are probably more `git` power-users who happen to use OSX than there are OSX power-users who happen to use `git`.)

Comment: Apple's version of git is part of Xcode, which uses keychain to store credentials for git servers, so it's reasonable (IMO) to assume that's exactly what has happened here. Try this: `strings /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git | grep -i keychain`

Comment: Yep, that command returns a single line that reads `osxkeychain`. I've never used XCode, as such, directly on this machine. I only installed it because something *else* that I wanted to install needed it to build. And that was before I had a need to do anything with git. Maybe if I had installed git some other way (Homebrew?) I might not have gotten this behavior. Thanks for connecting the dots for me.

Comment: You can just install git in homebrew alongside the Xcode version. As long as `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`, it will be used. (That's what I do.)